# Jquery change selector based on attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following html snippet:

```
<div id="review_sort_section" class="ieSucks">Sort by:    
    <a href="#" data-uid="date">Date</a>    
<a href="#" data-uid="rating">Rating</a> 
    <a href="#" data-uid="vote">Vote</a>        
</div>
```

How can I change the `a` selector of above code based on `attr` value of `data-uid` with the following html within `$(document).ready(function(){})`:

```
'<a href="#"  class="i-wrap ig-wrap-common i-sort-descend-common-wrap ig-wrap-common-r selected">' + 
            '<i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common"></i>Date</a>';
```

Comment: im using IE to view this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the actual answer to your question as exact as possible - I suspect you want to wrap the DATE in the I

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pUtR5/)

```
$(function() {    
  $('#review_sort_section a[data-uid="date"]')
    .addClass("i-wrap ig-wrap-common i-sort-descend-common-wrap ig-wrap-common-r selected")
    .html('<i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common">Date</i>');
});
```

Result:

```
<div id="review_sort_section" class="ieSucks">Sort by:    
  <a href="#" data-uid="date" class="i-wrap ig-wrap-common i-sort-descend-common-wrap ig-wrap-common-r selected"><i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common">Date</i></a>    
  <a href="#" data-uid="rating">Rating</a> 
  <a href="#" data-uid="vote">Vote</a>        
</div>
```

---

Assumption - you likely want this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="review_sort_section" class="ieSucks">Sort by:    
  <a href="#" data-uid="Date">Date</a>    
  <a href="#" data-uid="Rating">Rating</a> 
  <a href="#" data-uid="Vote">Vote</a>        
</div>
```

jQuery:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/SPkQQ/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#review_sort_section a").on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("i-wrap ig-wrap-common i-sort-descend-common-wrap ig-wrap-common-r selected")
          .html('<i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common">'+$(this).data("uid")+'</i>')
          .siblings().each(function() {
            $(this).html($(this).data("uid")).removeClass(); // siblings $(this)
          });

        // here we call the ajax to load the sorted data
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey buddy thanks for your help it's great effort, sorry couldn't reply yesterday. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the elements with specific value of attribute.

```
$('[data-uid="yourvalue"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-uid="date"]').parent().html('<a href="#"  class="i-wrap ig-wrap-common i-sort-descend-common-wrap ig-wrap-common-r selected">' + 
            '<i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common"></i>Date</a>');
});
```

That would generate this:

```
<div id="review_sort_section" class="ieSucks"> 
   <a href="#"  class="i-wrap ig-wrap-common i-sort-descend-common-wrap ig-wrap-common-r selected">
       <i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common"></i>Date
     </a>               
</div>
```

Here you have a living example added by @mplungjan: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/89ZhX

Comment: You need to use it inside the `$(document).ready(function(){` function.

Comment: I add your fiddle @mplungjan +1

Comment: it remove all the neighour link also

Comment: You didn't say anything about neighbour links... can you update your question?

Comment: Do you want to be able to toggle the action? After having clicked on it?

Answer (score 2):

this might work for you

`$('a[data-uid="yourValue"]').attr('class','your-class-name').html('<i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common"></i>Date');`

Answer (score 1):

try like this. use attribute selector [Attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('a[data-uid="yourValue"]');
```

Comment: I gave answer earlier, for the selector. later @steve added his answer